# Why am I getting inconsistent results with the RandomFields package?

Tags: r, optimization, geospatial

I am intrigued to see whether other users have similar results or suggestions as to why this could be happening. I extracted this code from the JSS paper [here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v63/i08/paper), Section 5, and I'm getting different results on different platforms. The algorithm is deterministic (not seed-dependent) and I cannot seem to find a pattern as to what is causing the discrepancies. Just a bit of background -- the aim of the following lines of code are to estimate parameters in a model using maximum likelihood:

```
library(RandomFields)
data(weather)
nug <- RMmatrix(M = matrix(nc = 2, c(NA, 0, 0, NA)), RMnugget())
pars.model <- nug + RMbiwm(nudiag = c(NA, NA), 
                           scale = NA, 
                           cdiag =   c(NA, NA), 
                           rhored = NA)
Dist.mat <- as.vector(RFearth2dist(weather[, 3:4]))
PT <- weather[, 1:2]
pars <- RFfit(pars.model, distances = Dist.mat, dim = 3, data = PT)
print(pars)
```

The output of the above is quite long but it is sufficient to compare the AIC values displayed, which reflect the optimum found by the `RFfit` routine. Across different platforms I got two sets of AIC values which are *very* different from a practical point of view

> CentOS 6 64-bit 64GB RAM Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz R
>   version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16) x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit) AIC:
>   2547.474
>
> CentOS 6 64-bit 256GB RAM AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6376 R version
>   3.2.0 (2015-04-16) x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit) AIC: 2562.027
>
> Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit 8GB RAM Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N2820  @ 2.13GHz
>   R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit) AIC:
>   2547.474
>
> Windows 7 64-bit 8GB RAM Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3632QM CPU @ 2.20GHz R
>   version 3.1.2 Patched (2014-11-25 r67060) i386-w64-mingw32/i386
>   (32-bit) AIC: 2547.474
>
> Windows 7 64-bit 8GB RAM Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3632QM CPU @ 2.20GHz R
>   version 3.1.2 Patched (2014-11-25 r67060) x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
>   (64-bit) AIC: 2562.027
>
> Windows 7 64-bit 8GB RAM Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3632QM CPU @ 2.20GHz R
>   version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) AIC:
>   2562.027

Venturing into the internals I find that the underlying optimisation routing is the standard R `optim` routine. Are such drasticly different results to be expected from any optimiser? Some of the below are using OpenBLAS, but OpenBLAS is not the cause of this. From below I cannot tease out whether it's the OS, the R version, the package version (they're all the same) or the CPU architectures... Any ideas on this appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In situations like this I try to believe that this is a consistent behavior and it will hold for all model likelihoods. Differences should thus be somewhat similar between setups.

Comment: Non R-user here: these results would not surprise me. A combination of matrix operations (e.g. ones with numerical trouble like matrix inversion) and randomized (my assumption about "optim") algorithms will always be trouble. 32-bit vs. 64-bit CPU may work differently, but the used linear algebra library should be more important: OpenBLAS, Atlas, MKL (Intel), ACML (AMD) should behave differently and maybe these tiny imprecisions are amplified by optim. Maybe some setup is using MKL instead of OpenBLAS. AMD-Setups may use ACML. OS + Package versions (if the same) should not be the reason.

Comment: Another remark (i still don't know anything about R's optim and your package): if your algorithm is randomized (my feeling about optim), maybe you can reduce the variance of the results by calculating more iterations in your core functions OR (this may cost more time): calculate several runs with different seeds.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. @sascha The matrix operations are nothing fancy here, there are inverses but only on the order of 100 x 100 which in my experience has never created such differences, even across different BLAS use. R is shipped with its own BLAS routines, however I tested above using both OpenBLAS and the R-specific one, there is no pattern. Also, the algorithm is not randomized, optim() implements a standard L-BFGS routine in this example. Also, I only get two sets of results, just cannot figure what causes which machine to give which!